# fetch data from ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/ftp.imdb.com/pub/ using java

Tags: java, web-applications, ftp, server

[image: Error what i am getting]how can I fetch movie.list.gz folder from the link 
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF5rx.png): ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/ftp.imdb.com/pub/, I have used a code to access the FTP server for fetching data but it asks for port no. which I don't know. Can anyone please tell how to fetch data from the above link in java. I am developing a Web Application which will display all the movie names present in IMDB database.

CODE:

```
 String server = "ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/ftp.imdb.com";
    int port = 21;


    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server);

        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        // APPROACH #1: using retrieveFile(String, OutputStream)
        String remoteFile1 = "/pub/movie.list.gz";
        File downloadFile1 = new File("F:/softwares/mov.list.gz");
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();

        if (success) {
            System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
        }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard FTP port numbers are 21 for control and 20 for data. You haven't indicated what the actual error or problem is that compiling/running this code present for you, so I'm voting to close as off-topic.